# Get the list of users who download an apps from google play store and app store

Tags: google-play, app-store

Is there anyway to get a list of users who download certain app on google play store or app store whether the app is belong to me (I am the owner) or not?

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Apple App Store you don't get any sales-related information that could identify your customers (i.e. Apple ID). You can only verify that someone purchased your app.

Source:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html